# A simple congruent equation $3^a\equiv1+b\mod m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

I come across a simple  congruent equation as follows:
let $m\geq 10$ be an integer.It is not a power of $3$. Then how can we find some $a$ and $b$ (they are integers) such that
$$3^a\equiv1+b\pmod{m},$$ where $b$ satisfies the condition:$\frac{m}3<b<\frac{2m}3.$

Comment: It is easy to find concrete solution if m=5,7,11, and so on. The key difficult part is how to conctruct a and b in terms of a general number m.

Comment: Such $a$ and $b$ need not exist, e.g. for $m=27$.

Comment: Yes. For the case m is power of 3, I think it is trivial. Even it does not have solution. My interest is when m is some other cases.  I edit the problem.

Comment: There's no solution for $m = 12,24,26,27,30,36,39,78,80,81,84,90,\dots$

Comment: Many thanks. I am still wondering when it has solutions.

Comment: The list I wrote is exhaustive for $10\le m \le 100$, so it does have solution in all the values not in the list.

Comment: If m is a prime number, then I think it is possible to have solutions.

Comment: Let's suppose $m$ is not a multiple of $3$. Then you are looking at the group generated by $3$ in the integers modulo $m$, and asking whether there's an element in the middle third of values.

Comment: @1011 Look at the edit in my question. For the prime $1093$ there's just one solution, and almost miss the interval. It's wouldn't surprise me if there were a prime for which there's no solution.

Comment: Many thanks. I learn a lot from this problem.  Thank you and Gerry Myerson!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a particular case where we can guarantee an answer.

Take $m>3$, $m\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Let $n = \mathrm{ord}_m(3)$, so $3^n\equiv 1 \pmod m$. This means that $3^n = mk+1$ for some $k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Since $k = 3l+2$ then $3^{n}= mk+1 = 3lm+2m+1$, so

$$3^{n-1}-1 = lm+\frac{2m-2}{3}$$

Reducing modulo $m$ we have

$$(3^{n-1}-1) \bmod m = \frac{2m-2}{3}$$ and

$$\frac{m}{3}<\frac{2m-2}{3}<\frac{2m}{3}$$

So in this case there's a solution $a = n-1$.

Comment: $k\equiv2\bmod3$ is the same thing as $m\equiv1\bmod3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know how I missed that, thanks. That improves my answer.

Comment: I am still a little confused  about $m\equiv1\mod 3.$ I try the same proof as you. But I cannot obtain the result, i.e. when $m=3t+1, t\in N$ the equation has a solution. Could you give more explanations. @jjagmath.

Comment: What part of the proof did you not understand?

Comment: When $m\equiv1\mod 3$, how can we claim that $3^n=mk+1$ for some $k\equiv 2\mod 3.$

Comment: From the definition of order modulo $m$ we have $3^n = mk+1$ for some integer $k$. Now consider that equality modulo $3$. We have $0 \equiv 1\cdot k +1 \pmod 3$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that  for some prime cases, we can make use the lifting exponent lemma to prove partial result.  I am still thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can solve for $b$, it is superfluous, so we may just simply ask if there exists $a$ such that $\frac{m}{3} < (3^a-1) \bmod m  < \frac{2m}{3}$.

I think it should be relatively easy to prove that there is a solution if $3$ is a primitive root modulo $m$. But no simple characterization of such $m$'s is known.

In fact, if $\mathrm{ord}_m 3$ is relatively big, one would expect to find some power of $3$ in the desired interval. But the problem is that even if $\mathrm{ord}_m 3$ is very small, it could still happen that there's a solution just by coincidence.

As general as it's asked, I don't think this can be answered. The distribution of the residues of sequences of powers (in this case $3^a$) is a very hard problem with a lot of open questions.

Edit:

Gerry Myerson gave me an excellent example of what I was saying. Consider $m =  1093$. The sequence $(3^a-1) \bmod 1093$ takes only seven values $0, 2, 8, 26, 80, 242, 728$. Only one of them lands on the interval $(\frac{1093}{3},\frac{2\cdot 1093}{3}) = (364.333\ldots, 728.666\ldots)$ and just barely!!

Comment: It might be worth checking $m=1093$.